# Why NSMapTable throw exception "count underflow"?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a weak-to-strong `NSMapTable`. When I try to call `removeObjectForKey:method` my app crashes.

The code is as follows:**self.requestedObjectMap is a weak-to-strong `NSMapTable`**

```
NSUInteger countBefore = [self.requestedObjectMap count];
[self.requestedObjectMap removeObjectForKey:object];
NSUInteger countAfter = [self.requestedObjectMap count];
```

Stack as follows：**how can I trigger this exception "[NSMapTable NSMapTable {\n}\n] count underflow" ?**

```
"signal": {
        "signal": 6,
        "name": "SIGABRT",
        "code": 0
    },
    "address": 0,
    "reason": "*** -[NSMapTable NSMapTable {\n}\n] count underflow",
    "type": "nsexception",
    "nsexception": {
        "name": "NSInternalInconsistencyException"
    }
```

Please help me out, thanks and expect for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you are passing the reference to your object,

make it like that :

```
NSMapTable *mapTableView = [self.mapTableView mutableCopy];
```

Comment: what's the difference between A and B ?Forgive me that I don't get your point ~


A:
[self.requestedObjectMap removeObjectForKey:object];

B:
NSMapTable *mapTableView = [self.requestedObjectMap mutableCopy];
[mapTableView removeObjectForKey:object];

Actually,I wanna remove object from self.requestedObjectMap,not it's copy

Answer (score 0):

This is happen when you remove key in multiple threads

```
NSMapTable *map = [NSMapTable strongToStrongObjectsMapTable];
dispatch_apply(1000, DISPATCH_APPLY_AUTO, ^(__unused size_t t) {
    @synchronized (self) {
        [map setObject:@"1" forKey:@(t)];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        [map removeObjectForKey:@(t)];
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Fengxing. Can you explain this a little further?
I ran this code; it works. Removing @synchronized causes a bad access. Can you break down what is going on here?

Comment: @synchronized self blocks the code path so that it can only be executed one at a time. If some other concurrent methods call this block it will hold up the setObject call until they're all done in order.